# How to construct a case class for this json input and convert it to an object?

Tags: scala, spray-json

I get this Json string from a web api:

```
{"results":{"Inne":"23.3","Ute":"5.8"}}
```

How do I construct a case class to match this output?

---

This is my attempt:

```
case class Results(Inne: String, Ute: String)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val tempsFormat = jsonFormat2(Results)
}
```

I try to convert with val temps = jsonin.convertTo[Results] and obvious this does not work since it expects only two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case class Results(Inne: String, Ute: String )
case class Result(results: Results)
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val tempsFormat = jsonFormat2(Results)
    implicit val resultsFormat = jsonFormat1(Results)
}
```

Or you can use lenses https://github.com/jrudolph/json-lenses

```
case class Results(Inne: String, Ute: String )
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val tempsFormat = jsonFormat2(Results)
    implicit val resultsFormat = jsonFormat1(Results)
}

jsonin.extract[Results]('results)
```

Comment: I guess that implicit val resultsFormat = jsonFormat1(Results) should be:
implicit val resultsFormat = jsonFormat1(Result)?

Comment: Lenses is really neat! Problem solved! Thanks a lot for your help @Falmarri.